# export data to excel using oledb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I need to export big data by means (only oldb).
I have a List with about 100k entries. How can I write it in Excel?
You will help a lot!

```
OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; 
      data source = D:\5.xlsx; 
      Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0'");
        oleDbConnection.Open();
        OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Rock$] " + "([Имя],[Фамилия],[Отчество]) " + "VALUES(@value1,@value2,@value3)");
        oleDbCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection;
        List<info> test = date.AsNoTracking().ToList();

        //Add list In excel use oledb


        oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        oleDbConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for OleDb, but I would like to share my experience with [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) package. I was surprised how fast it is. Below is my test example:

**List initialization**

```
static void Main()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var list = new List<Info>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new Info() { prop1 = random.Next().ToString(), 
                              prop2 = random.Next().ToString(), 
                              prop3 = random.Next().ToString() });
    }
    SaveListToExcel(@"D:\5.xlsx", list);
}
```

**Saving list**

```
private static void SaveListToExcel(string filePath, IEnumerable<Info> list)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
    if (f.Exists) f.Delete();
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
    using (ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage(f))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet sheet = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Rock");
        sheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Имя"; ;
        sheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Фамилия";
        sheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Отчество";
        sheet.Cells[2, 1].LoadFromCollection(list);
        ep.Save();
    }
}
```

**Info class**

```
public class Info
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
}
```